# How to test toggle button in recyclerview is on or off at specific position using espresso android?

Tags: android, android-espresso

In activity_main.xml, I am using TextView with id info to display inforamtion of clicked text in recycler_view list with id item_name. Recycler view is displaying a list of 100 items with its name and toggle to make them active and inactive.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context="com.app.recyclerviewtesting.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="eraseInfo"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#999999" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Item i.e used in recycler view:
Here is my item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.app.recyclerviewtesting.Item" />

    <variable
        name="listener"
        type="com.app.recyclerviewtesting.AdapterItemsClickHandler" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="@{() -> listener.onItemNameClick(item)}"
        android:text="@{item.name}"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="@{item.on}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> listener.onToggleClick(item)}"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

public static final String ITEM_NAME_FORMAT = "Item :%d";
public static final String ITEM_SELECTED_FORMAT = "%s is selected.";
public static final String INFO_HINT = "Click on item!";
private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;
private List<Item> mMainList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {

    mBinding.info.setHint(INFO_HINT);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mMainList.add(new Item(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ITEM_NAME_FORMAT, i), false));
    }
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mMainList, new HandleAdapterActions());
    mBinding.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public void eraseInfo(View view) {
    mBinding.info.setText("");
}

private class HandleAdapterActions implements AdapterItemsClickHandler {

    @Override
    public void onItemNameClick(Item item) {
        mBinding.info.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ITEM_SELECTED_FORMAT, item.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onToggleClick(Item item) {
        item.setOn(!item.getOn());
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(mMainList.indexOf(item));
    }
}
}
```

Here is Adapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> 
{

private final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
private List<Item> mainList;
private AdapterItemsClickHandler mListener;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<Item> mainList, AdapterItemsClickHandler mListener) {
    this.mainList = mainList;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (viewType == ITEM_VIEW_TYPE) {
        final ItemBinding binding = ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        binding.setListener(mListener);
        viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(binding);
    } else {
        viewHolder = null;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        final ItemBinding binding = itemViewHolder.binding;

        Item item = mainList.get(position);
        binding.setItem(item);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mainList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ItemBinding binding;

    ItemViewHolder(ItemBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
}
```

Please help me to find the way to write a test case if toggle on position 15th is on or off.

Comment: take a Boolean field in you model and update status of this field to true/false    for toggle ON/Off when clicked . also Check togglebtn.isChecked() to get and togglebtn.setChecked(true/false); to set value .

Comment: also look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017498/toggle-switch-in-recyclerview-programatically

Comment: This functionality  is already working. I just want know how to write test case for this with espresso. See android:checked="@{item.on}" in item.xml and binding.setItem(item); in adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for this problem:

```
 public static Matcher<View> withToggleMatcher(final int position) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            final RecyclerAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerAdapter.ItemViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
            return viewHolder.binding.toggle.isChecked();
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void checkIfToggleIsOnAfterClickOnIt() {

    int position = 15;

    String itemName = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), MainActivity.ITEM_NAME_FORMAT, position);

    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(position));

    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.toggle), hasSibling(withText(itemName))))
            .perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
            .check(matches(withToggleMatcher(position)));
}
```